# How to find minimal swapping in two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

Given two positive integer arrays: A and B with same length. You can swapping elements between A and B.

Here is my problem.

Minimize `total_number_of_swap(A,B)`
subject to `|sum(A)-sum(B)| ≤ delta`

delta is a constant.

e.g.

```
A={4,2,3} , B={5,6,7} and delta=1
```

The one solution is `total_number_of_swap(A,B)=1 (swap(A[2],B[2]))`

```
A'={4,2,7}, B'={5,6,3}  

sum(A)=4+2+7=13, sum(B)=5+6+3=14 

|sum(A)-sum(B)| ≤ 1
```

How to find A' and B'.

Anybody have the algorithm to solve this problem? If you got, please tell me and I would be very grateful of you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a "do my HW for me" kind of website. Here you have to show some effort, research, what have you tried, where have you failed etc. Good luck!

Comment: Can you swap A[1] with B[2]?

Comment: You swap A[1] with B[2] . A'={4,7,3} B'={5,6,2} .sum(A)=14 and sum(B)=13
|sum(A)-sum(B)| <=1  and total_number_of_swap(A,B)=1. It can swap . There have many solution I want algorithm to find one.

Comment: This looks NP-hard even without the minimization goal, any side conditions like very small number of elements or small range of values?

Comment: It's only weakly NP-hard...

Comment: I think like NP-hard but i don't sure

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is an extension to the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). To solve it

1. Put all numbers into one set and solve the Partition Problem (NP-Complete)
2. Since you know the best solution from Step1, you know which element should belong to A and B. Swap those elements that are in the wrong set. (O(n) = Linear)